# iOS: HTML copied from iMessage introduces invisible symbol/character in rendered web page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uitextview

The app lets you run HTML/JavaScript/CSS on an iOS device without a server.

You paste HTML/JS/CSS into a UITextView, and the app renders the web page in a separate WKWebView.

Writing the code fresh into the UITextView renders normally, but copying and pasting the same code from iMessage introduces an unexpected symbol/character, the Latin capital letter A with circumflex (Ã).

What's the right way to handle the iMessage special formatting without inadvertently altering valid HTML/JS/CSS?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <style type="text/css">
                html, body { width: 100%; padding: 10px;  box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; background-color: #F5F5ED; font-size: 16px; font-family: Verdana; color: #7C7A7D }
            </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        Hello!
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS Fiddle Output:** https://jsfiddle.net/fvbcfmeg/

**App Output:**

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to view what the special formatting of the iMessage is? Like can you view what the HTML actually is that it's trying to display?

Comment: @CharlieFish not sure. :) this is a great question, though! put another way, you're asking how to view all the invisible characters in some block of text.